# No longer needed comments flagged but declined, why?

Tags: support, comments, declined-flags, comment-flags

I am used to always flag comments like *thank you*, *please accept the answer*, *This is awesome!*, etc and they all get accepted or even automatically deleted but recently I got two declined flags and I didn't understand why.

[image]

Are these comments really needed?

Comment: I'm hoping for a misclick. Declining these flags seems really weird otherwise. We automatically block "+1" comments but then decline flags on "Thumbs up" comments?

Comment: I flagged them again, lets wait and see.

Comment: I'm with @yivi on this, can't see this as being anything but a misclick.

Comment: I think the policy changed recently, and "thank you" comments are now OK. Personally, I used to be against "thank you" comments, but I changed my mind after my heart was warmed by a few lovely "thank you" comments over the years (all subsequently deleted), I think we should let the positivity rain!

Comment: @Flimm well, a "thank you" comment is never bad and can be good but after few months we can delete it I guess. You answered me, I thank you and now let's keep only the needed information and remove the noises

Comment: @Flimm SO is still not a social network, but a technical Q/A repository. IMO, thanks comments are just noise and should be avoided and removed. We have a voting system to express your gratitude for useful answers.

Comment: @Baum In these days where *everything* is a social network, people may have a harder time wrapping their heads around that.

Comment: @deceze That might be true, but I don't think we have to just give up on this front. After all, you don't see e.g. Wikipedia cluttered with "Thanks for the correction" comments either. A community can still set and enforce rules and standards without being "rude"
 or "evil" for that. At least that's how I see it.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thanks for the comment

Comment: @BaummitAugen But the wikipedia is IMHO a _colaborative_ platform, not an _interaction_ platform like SO, which I think would be "in between" the wiki and social networks. People comunicating with other people, asking and answering, providing help and advice. It's only human to being thankful and wanting to express it.

Comment: @guillermochamorro SO is also a collaborative platform, with the goal of building a high-quality and searchable programming Q/A repository. The "social interaction" has always been clear second to the main goal, see e.g. declined FRs to allow subscribing to certain users and similar stuff. Now of course we don't go around punishing people for posting thank-you comments or ending their  questions with a thanks, but the SO way to say thanks is still built into the voting system. Using e.g. comments for that is (mild) misuse.

Comment: @Baum mit Augen: Where SO differs from Wikipedia is that it puts user cards with names and pictures at the end of every non-wiki question and answer. There is a clear notion of personal authorship tied to each post, which makes social interaction inevitable. It's very difficult to bill SO as a purist like Wikipedia, or prevent people from saying thanks in the comments, when community wiki isn't the default. Now, whether or not the community is willing to see SO turn purist by completely depersonalizing its user-generated content, is another story...

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Well, not much I can say about this, other than offering an apology. I honestly don't remember handling these flags, but there's absolutely no way I'd deliberately decline them.

As yivi [commented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374364/no-longer-needed-comments-flagged-but-declined-why#comment631891_374364), this was definitely a mistake. Those flags should have been marked helpful. I've now deleted the comments.

Sorry, I'll try to be a bit more careful with my clicks in the future!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is really helpful  (don't delete this one too fast :p)

Comment: No [paper bag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310352/369403)? :(

Comment: @Temani Afif: I think 8 months is a pretty good time to wait before deleting your comment. (The comments you flagged were 8 months old.)